# Equivalent statements about unconditionally convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

### Problem

I want to show the following equivalence:

> **Problem.** Let $T\subseteq\mathbb R$ be a bounded set with at least two elements. A series $\sum_k a_k$ in a banach space $E$ is perfectly convergent (see definition below) iff $\sum_k \theta_k a_k$ converges for every sequence $(\theta_k)$ in $T$.

Here, perfectly convergent means:

> **Definition**. A series $\sum_k a_k$ in a banach space $E$ is *perfectly convergent* iff for every sequence $(\alpha_k)$ with $\alpha_k\in\{-1,1\}$ for $k\in\mathbb N$ the series $\sum_k \alpha_k a_k$ converges.

So my problem is to show that perfect convergence with sequences in $\{-1,1\}$ can be generalized to sequences in an arbitrary bounded set $T$ with $|T|\geq 2$.

### What I already know

Perfect convergence is an important property for series, because it is equivalent to unconditional convergence:

> **Definition**. A series $\sum_k a_k$ in a banach space $E$ is said to be *unconditionally convergent* iff every rearrangement converges, i.e. for each permutation $\pi\colon\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$  the series $\sum_k a_{\pi(k)}$ converges.

One can also show, that a series $\sum_k a_k$ in $E$ is perfectly convergent iff every subseries converges, i.e. $\sum_k a_{\sigma(k)}$ converges for every strictly increasing mapping $\sigma\colon\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$.

All equivalences are shown in "Kadets, V. (2011, November 11). Series in Banach Spaces: Conditional and Unconditional Convergence (Operator Theory: Advances and Applications, 94) (1997th ed.). Birkhäuser."
Except for the first equivalence, it is listed as an exercise in the book.

### My approach

I list some ideas for both directions of the proof:

- $\theta_k$ is bounded, hence there is a convergent subsequence with limit in the closure of $T$. But I don't know how to implement this fact in my proof.
- We can assume that $0\notin T$ without loss of generality, because otherwise we could reduce to subseries. Hence $\sum_k \frac{\theta_k}{|\theta_k|}a_k$ convergences if we assume perfect convergence. But I can't deduce the convergence of $\sum_k \theta_k a_k$ from it, although I know that $|\theta_k|\leq \theta$ for some $\theta>0$.
- Perhaps I can use methods from functional analysis, because the series $(\theta_k)$ lies in $\ell^\infty$. But I haven't found anything in the literature on this yet.

Comment: I cannot imagine why someone downvoted this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show that the following two statements are equivalent:
$\def\abajo{\\[0.3cm]}$ $\def\x\{E}$ $\def\Re{\operatorname{Re}}$ $\def\ds{\displaystyle}$ $\def\NN{\mathbb N}$

1. $\ds\sum_k\theta_kx_k$ converges for all $\theta\in\{-1,1\}^\NN$;
2. $\ds\sum_k\theta_kx_k$ converges for all $\theta\in T^\NN$

1$\implies$2. The proof relies on the following equality: given $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\x$,

\begin{equation}\tag1
\max\Big\{\Big\|\sum_{k=1}^n \theta_kx_k\Big\|:\ \theta_k\in[-1,1]\Big\}
=\max\Big\{\Big\|\sum_{k=1}^n \theta_kx_k\Big\|:\ \theta_k=\pm1\Big\}
\end{equation}
*(one would initially write $\sup$ instead of $\max$, but it is easy to check that all  sets are continuous images of compact domains; in any case, the proof does not change if one writes sup instead of max).*

Having equality $(1)$, we get that $\sum_k\theta_kx_k$ converges for all $\theta\in\ell^\infty(\NN)$ (since any $\theta\in\ell^\infty(\NN)$ can be rescaled to the unit disk, and real and imaginary parts can be considered separately).

2$\implies$1. Let $t_1,t_2\in T$, with $t_1\ne t_2$. Let $\{n_k\}\subset\NN$ be a sequence. Write $G=\{n_k\}$ and let
$$
\theta_k=\begin{cases} t_1,&\ k\in \NN\setminus G\abajo t_2,&\ k\in G\end{cases}
$$By hypothesis, the series
$$
\sum_k t_1x_k\qquad\text{ and } \qquad \sum_k \theta_k\,x_k
$$
converge. Then their difference also converges, and this is
$$
\sum_kt_1x_k-\sum_k\theta_kx_k=\sum_{k\in G}(t_1-t_2)x_k=(t_1-t_2)\sum_k x_{n_k}.
$$
This shows that $\sum_kx_{n_k}$ converges for any increasing sequence $\{n_k\}$, and hence the series converges unconditionally.

---

**Proof of  $(1)$**. One proves
\begin{aligned}
\max\Big\{\Big\|\sum_{k=1}^n \theta_kx_k\Big\|:\ \theta_k\in[-1,1]\Big\}
&=\max\Big\{\sum_{k=1}^n|\Re g(x_k)|:\ g\in\x^*,\ \|g\|=1\Big\}\abajo
&=\max\Big\{\Big\|\sum_{k=1}^n \theta_kx_k\Big\|:\ \theta_k=\pm1\Big\}
\end{aligned}

Let $g\in\x^*$ with $\|g\|=1$ and $\ds g\Big(\sum_{k=1}^n\theta_kx_k\Big)=\Big\|\sum_{k=1}^n\theta_kx_k\Big\|$ (this is an easy consequence of Hahn-Banach). Then
\begin{align*}
\Big\|\sum_{k=1}^n\theta_kx_k\Big\|
&=g\Big(\sum_{k=1}^n\theta_kx_k\Big)=\Re g\Big(\sum_{k=1}^n\theta_kx_k\Big)=\sum_{k=1}^n\theta_k \Re g(x_k)\abajo
&\leq\sum_{k=1}^n|\theta_k|\,|\Re g(x_k)|\leq\sum_{k=1}^n|\Re g(x_k)|.
\end{align*}
Conversely, given $g\in\x^*$ with $\|g\|=1$ choose $\theta_k\in\{1,-1\}$ so that $\theta_k \Re g(x_k)=|\Re g(x_k)|$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n |\Re g(x_k)|=\sum_{k=1}^n \theta_k\Re g(x_k)=\Re g\Big(\sum_{k=1}^n \theta_kx_k\Big)\leq\Big\|\sum_{k=1}^n \theta_kx_k\Big\|, 
$$
completing the proof of the first line. The equality with the last line follows easily from the fact that in the proof of the first line we chose all $\theta_k$ with $\theta_k=\pm1$.

Comment: This is exactly the approach I had not thought of: Introduce a suitable functional to allow fitting estimations. I always had the problem that direct estimations of $\lVert\sum_{k=1}^n \theta_k a_k\rVert$ did not work, because they mostly require absolute convergence.

Comment: I think it is possible to use a functional $g\colon E\rightarrow\mathbb R$ instead of a complex-valued one, because the theorem of Hahn-Banach holds both for $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$. Then the proof becomes a little shorter by omitting "Re" in some parts.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But if your space is complex then you need to specify that $g$ is real, so the gain in length is not so :D

Comment: :D that makes sense

Comment: I noticed that the argument I had provided did not show one of the implications. I have completed it now.

Comment: I don't know if this error was only appearing for me , but the `\ds` and `\nn` operators were not executed on my machine, and therefore I couldn't read those parts. By shifting the definitions before their usage I managed to rectify it locally at least. +1, this question-answer pair is very interesting.

Comment: I probably messed up on my last edit. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, @MartinArgerami. Maybe I haven't told you this, but I've got a friend who is a budding operator algebraist, and he often refers to your answers on this site for help. He doesn't have an account (yet), but I've asked him to freely go through your answers. On his behalf, I'd like to thank you for your contributions.

Comment: That's so nice to hear. Thanks!