Sufficient and necessary conditions for weakly convergence sequence in a NLS.
$X$ is a normed linear space, with $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ being the sequence in $X$.
$X^*$ is the dual space of $X$, show that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lvert f(x_n)\lvert<\infty,\forall f\in X^*\Leftrightarrow\exists M>0, s.t. \forall m\in \mathbb{N}, \varepsilon_n\in\{\pm1\}, \Vert \sum_{n=1}^{m}\varepsilon_nx_n\Vert\le M.
$$
$\Rightarrow$: For this part, according to Hahn-Banach Theorem, i can find a linear functional $f$, such that $f(x_n)=\Vert x_n\Vert,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, which leads to the sequence $\Vert x_n\Vert$ converges to zero, thus the conclusion might be solved easilly.
$\Leftarrow$ For this part, I can show that $\forall f\in X^*$, it is bounded on the set$\{\sum_{n=1}^{m}\varepsilon_nx_n\}$ i.e.$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\varepsilon_nx_n$ is weakly bounded, after that, $\sum_{n=1}^m\lvert f(x_n)\lvert<+\infty$. However, i failed to push forward. Hopefully someone can teach me how to deal with this part. Thank you for taking the time to solve my question.

See this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4556877/739818

Thanks for your hints, but I still don't understand how this is related to weak convergence. Would you like to expand on that?

Your post has nothing to do with convergence, it is precisely equation (1) in my reference

You are right, it seems that the question should be considered under a Banach space. Thanks for your help.

If you have found the answer please close this question

Just in case the question is still unanswered. Here is the answer.
Assuming we are in a real normed linear space.
Let $f\in X^*,\ m\in \mathbb{N}$ then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^m |f(x_n)| = \sum\limits_{n=1}^m$sign($f(x_n)$)$f(x_n)$
Let $\epsilon_n =\ $sign($f(x_n)$) then the above summation becomes
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^m$sign($f(x_n)$)$f(x_n) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^m \epsilon_nf(x_n) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^m f(\epsilon_nx_n)$
So that
$||\sum\limits_{n=1}^m f(\epsilon_nx_n)||\leq ||f||\cdot ||\sum\limits_{n=1}^m \epsilon_nx_n|| \leq ||f||M$
Then by letting $m \rightarrow \infty$ we get the required result.
